# jquery/ajax shoutbox does not refresh content but does submit

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, refresh

I am currently making a shoutbox for a band website. It is almost done (except for styling of it).
The whole concept of the shoutbox works. You can enter your name and message and it will submit.
However there is a function in the script that makes the div refresh. This somehow doesnt work.
You can try it here:
http://basenharald.nl/3d/#shoutbox

If you submit, you will not see you message, now if you hit F5 you will. Meaning the shoutbox works, it simply does not refresh.

I used the same code that is used here:
http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-shoutbox.html

I think the jquery script somehow conflicts with the other scripts?

Could anyone please provide me a codesnippet to get this code working? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This happens to me on the sample page as well. If I submit once and then submit another shoutout, it doesn't refresh. Only after clicking refresh I see the second shoutout I entered.

Comment: I have some problem to use your shoutbox, the picture was over it i remove it with firebox :o

Comment: I didn't seem to be able to click on the input boxes in Firefox or Chrome. I guess dues to the picture issue mentioned by Awea.

Comment: Do you only want your website to work on IEs?

Comment: No I dont, i will focus on these issues later.

Comment: Just so you guys know, it works now also in chrome and ff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is added to the page. You can see it in the DOM. It is however never shown because your script never sets the elements style.display to 'block'.

The call to `$('input[@name=message]').attr('value', '').focus();` (line 316) raise an unrecognized expression error generated by jQuery.

It seems you are using a newer version of jQuery. Which causes causes the error.

Removing this line should make it work again. To fix the line I think you only need to remove the '@'

Comment: Thank you so much Gerben, works like a charm. I was looking for a needle in a haystack. Don't know why i didn't think of this simple solution. Enjoy your bounty :)